# how to add linux kernel and boot loader to an Ubuntu 14.0.4 core rootfs for Raspberry Pi2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi2, u-boot

As the title suggests I am trying to use the [Ubuntu 14.0.4 base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) rootfs for armhf to create a minimal Ubuntu image for my Raspberry-Pi2.

I have to add the Kernel and a Boot Loader to the mix myself, and since I'm not Pro in this topic I am totally confused by all the different guides for compiling a Kernel / U-boot. Couldn't find anything to cover the whole process and get the RPi to boot.

Is there anyone who can help me with the procedure of slapping a kernel and a boot loader onto the Ubuntu (core) rootfs for RPi2 and create a bootable SD card (from scratch)?

PS: I would like a step-by-step guide for the whole process so that I (and anyone else like me) can apply them locally and get a Pi2 up and running from scratch.

I have an Ubuntu 14.0.4 laptop as my Host machine for cross-compiling and copying files, etc.

I'm desperate, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the official releases [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)? The general procedure of having an SD card is to have two partitions for the SD card. First partition will be FAT32 in which your bootloader, device tree blob and kernel image can reside and any other file. RPi requires quite a few other binary blobs in the first partition if I remember correctly. The second will be an ext partition in which you need to put the rootfs. Take any available distribution image, write it to the SD card and replace the second rootfs partition with any distro rootfs you did like. It is also possible that the kernel and device tree blob reside on the /boot of the second partition instead of the first.

I also just quickly checked. I had an SD card for RPi3 which had Raspbian on it. I replaced the second partition which had rootfs from Raspbian with the Ubuntu based rootfs. It boots perfectly fine but stalls at

```
 * Starting Mount filesystems on boot[ OK ]
 * Starting Populate /dev filesystem[ OK ]
 * Stopping Populate /dev filesystem[ OK ]
 * Starting Populate and link to /run filesystem[ OK ]
 * Stopping Populate and link to /run filesystem[ OK ]
 * Stopping Track if upstart is running in a container[ OK ]
 * Starting Initialize or finalize resolvconf[ OK ]
 * Starting set console keymap[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that virtual filesystems are mounted[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge udev events into upstart[ OK ]
 * Starting device node and kernel event manager[ OK ]
 * Starting Signal sysvinit that remote filesystems are mounted[ OK ]
 * Stopping set console keymap[ OK ]
 * Starting load modules from /etc/modules[ OK ]
 * Starting cold plug devices[ OK ]
 * Starting log initial device creation[ OK ]
 * Stopping load modules from /etc/modules[ OK ]
 * Starting set console font[ OK ]
 * Stopping set console font[ OK ]
 * Starting userspace bootsplash[ OK ]
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up[ OK ]
 * Stopping userspace bootsplash[ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up[ OK ]
 * Stopping cold plug devices[ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge socket events into upstart[ OK ]
The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present.
keys:Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I did not investigate the reason but I believe it's due to the /etc/fstab.

```
[root@alarmpi ~]# cat /etc/fstab 
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot   vfat    defaults        0       0
```

This is from Arch. I did not note down Ubuntu's but it was incorrect.

Replacing the rootfs with ArchLinux ARM based rootfs and it seems to boot fine. Note that I took a Raspbian based SD card and swapped the rootfs with Arch's.

```
[    3.743064] systemd-journald[85]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.791472] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup

Arch Linux 4.1.18-v7+ (ttyS0)

alarmpi login: 
Arch Linux 4.1.18-v7+ (ttyS0)

alarmpi login: root
Password: 
Welcome to Arch Linux ARM

     Website: http://archlinuxarm.org
       Forum: http://archlinuxarm.org/forum
         IRC: #archlinux-arm on irc.Freenode.net
[   15.258407] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

I hope this gives you enough of a general idea on how to approach this.